# Array containing one element containing a number of objects which I'd like to be elements of array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of one element containing several objects. I don't know how to work with these objects.  I'd like each object to be turned into an element of an array, so that I'll be able to refer to Array[0].Time to get "36:50" or Array[2].Seconds to get 2235.

Link to Json: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json

Comment: Per looking at the data, it’s already an array of objects. So you can just traverse the array with a for each and then you’ll get each single object to access those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's very easy to deal with objects I converted it for you in arrays. Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through your array over the objects and map every old entry to a new one.
Create for each element a new empty array and add to this for every entry a new entry. Use for this [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the values.

**Note:** The sequence from the entries in the array I can't change without extra programming and it's mandatory that the objects allways have this structure (otherwise the output would change).

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "Time": "36:50",
    "Place": 1,
    "Seconds": 2210,
    "Name": "Marco Pantani",
    "Year": 1995,
    "Nationality": "ITA",
    "Doping": "Alleged drug use during 1995 due to high hematocrit levels",
    "URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Pantani#Alleged_drug_use"
  },
  {
    "Time": "36:55",
    "Place": 2,
    "Seconds": 2215,
    "Name": "Marco Pantani",
    "Year": 1997,
    "Nationality": "ITA",
    "Doping": "Alleged drug use during 1997 due to high hermatocrit levels",
    "URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Pantani#Alleged_drug_use"
  },
  {
    "Time": "37:15",
    "Place": 3,
    "Seconds": 2235,
    "Name": "Marco Pantani",
    "Year": 1994,
    "Nationality": "ITA",
    "Doping": "Alleged drug use during 1994 due to high hermatocrit levels",
    "URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Pantani#Alleged_drug_use"
  },
  {
    "Time": "37:36",
    "Place": 4,
    "Seconds": 2256,
    "Name": "Lance Armstrong",
    "Year": 2004,
    "Nationality": "USA",
    "Doping": "2004 Tour de France title stripped by UCI in 2012",
    "URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Lance_Armstrong_doping_allegations"
  }];
  
  let res = arr.map(obj => {
        let arr = [];
      Object.values(obj).forEach(val => arr.push(val));
      return arr;
  });
  
  console.log(res);
```